# Why would or would have

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

B has done something bad that A hadn't ever expected B to do so A is asking B

> 1- A: Why ***would*** ***you*** ***do*** that? I don't understand.

---

> 2- A: Why ***would*** ***have*** ***you*** ***done*** that? I don't understand.

What is the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 1):

*Why would you do that?* is a question in the present tense. And by convention the present tense is used for reasoning in general, so it might be applied to the past.

*Why would have you done that?* inquires specifically about the reasoning and conditions that may have affected your mood about doing something in the past (which may or may not have happened, or been done by you).

People are not always this deliberate. But not only does the second question ask after the past, the change in word order subtly reorients the interrogator in terms of skepticism. Consider the difference:

Me: I once boxed a jellyfish while skydiving.

Gullible Niece: You have done that?

Storyteller: I once arm wrestled a kangaroo.

My Slightly Older, Wiser Niece: Have you done that?

In the first case, I can probably keep telling her ridiculous nonsense. In the second case, the jig is probably up and it's time to find something more interesting to do.

Answer (score 0):

- Why would you do that?

Implication: A person would do something if something else happened.

Formal grammar pairs **would** with simple past** or was/were:

- I **would see** you tonight if you **arrived** tonight.

It is hypothetical, it hasn't happened. It is spoken in the present about something that has not occurred.

- Why would you have done that?

That is for something that has already happened. **Past conditional tense.**

I would have done it if I could.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly the second sentence needs rearranging:

> Why would **you have** done that? I don't understand.

The sentence:

> Why would you do that? I don't understand.

This sentence asks why B would do something, and sort implies that B would do it again, as though it were a part of who he is. It's much more direct, i.e., directed at B as a person.

> Why would you have done that? I don't understand.

This sentence places the emphasis in the past, at the time when B did the thing. It expresses curiosity and a desire to understand with regards to what B was experiencing at that time, and urges B to investigate not so much himself, but what he was experiencing at the time, or what might have influenced him to do such a thing at that time.

Comment: *"... places the emphasis in the **past**, at the time when B did the thing"* is that the only interpretation? We use "would have" with hypothetical scenarios too, then why is that not an option?

Comment: @Chris Mack Thank you but as far as I know native speakers also use "why would you do something" for situations that happened in the past. So what is the difference between them when "would you do" is used as I explained above?

Comment: The difference in emphasis comes from the words "do" and "done", with "do" implying that this is something characteristic of B, and less of a point in time. It is referring to the past event, but directed more at B's character than at the past event.

Comment: @AIQ, it's the only option in this case, as we're not talking about a hypothetical.

Comment: No no, no no no. Why would have you done that? questions the motive of something you *would have* done. Why would you have done that? questions the motive of something you *did*. These are different things.

Comment: @sas08: “Why would have you done that” is not proper English, it reads merely as an incorrect syntax of your other phrasing.

Comment: @ChrisMack Do you think it's an illegal construction, or do you think he's using in incorrectly? Because you haven't said what rule of syntax it violates. We change the subject position around in English all of the time to imply different things. Though we would probably correct an Eastern European fan of Mr. Rogers if he were to sing, "You would be my neighbor?" it is a legitimate question if you disbelieve that someone will be your neighbor.

Comment: @ChrisMack Messing with ngram here... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&year_end=2019&content=would+have+you%2Cwould+you+have&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20have%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwould%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @sas08 I just know it's not proper English. A google search for "why would have you" returns only 5 results, one of which is this question.

Comment: @ChrisMack Confirmed. Your source is "trust me bro." Just checking.

Comment: @ChrisMack The string "you would be my neighbor" only shows up eighteen (18) times on google compared to "would you be my neighbor" (450,000). Doesn't mean you can't use one or the other in English.

Comment: @sas08 I checked that too and for me it shows over 100,000 results(?). It’s a different type of phrase, and is totally acceptable.

Comment: @ChrisMack Hum. Are you bracketing the search query in double marks? I double checked, still geting 18 v 450,000.

Comment: Yep, 718,000: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+would+be+my+neighbor%22&oq=%22you+would+be+my+neighbor%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.598j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110672/discussion-between-sas08-and-chris-mack).